# Deleting a single translation from a model in a Rails project using Mobility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, mobility

I'm migrating a Rails project from Globalize to Mobility. With Globalize, I had access to the current translation through the `translation` method:

```
feature.translation
```

I used this mainly when managing translations for a model to delete a specific translation:

```
feature.translation.destroy
```

With Globalize, for each object, I get the list of translations and create a delete button for each:

```
<%= link_to 'x', admin_feature_path(list_item, translation_locale: l), method: :delete, data: { confirm: %(Are you sure you want to delete this #{humanize_locale l} translation? This cannot be undone.) } %>
```

I use the locale passed in with the link to delete the appropriate translation:

```
Mobility.with_locale(translation_locale) do
  @feature.tranlsation.destroy
end
```

Is there a straight-forward way of deleting a single translation from a model with multiple translations?

Comment: Why dont you directly update `hstore/json` field in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really nothing special about Mobility here. You've got a model with an association `translations`, each `translation` has a `locale`.

So to destroy a translation, you can just find it and destroy it:

```
translation = feature.translations.find { |t| t.locale == Mobility.locale.to_s }
translation.destroy
```

If you want the method like Globalize has, just add it to your model:

```
def translation
  translations.find { |t| t.locale == Mobility.locale.to_s }
end
```

That's it!

Comment: `translations.find { |t| t.locale == Mobility.locale }` returns `nil`. Since `translations` returns a `DownloadType::Translation::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` object, it looks like this works: `translations.where(locale: Mobility.locale).first`

Comment: Ah sorry, there was a missing `to_s` there, fixed now (should be `Mobility.locale.to_s`). You shouldn't use `where` because that won't work unless all translations are persisted.